# Automator application to open link?

Tags: automator

I use a browser launched from the command line (Qutebrowser) and I'd like to make an automator application that takes a URL as input and launches it via a shell script, `qutebrowser "$@" &> /dev/null &"` so I can set it as a default browser, open links from other applications, etc. The problem is, it seems like Automator apps can only accept local files and folders as input. Is there any way around this? I emphatically do not want to make a *service* which cannot be used as a default application as far as I know.